# System stuck at when trying to upgrade Ubuntu from 20.04 to 22.04

Tags: boot

I was trying to upgrade my system to 22.04 but ended up at this, now I'm not able to even shutdown my system. Help please. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HImSK.jpg)

Comment: Pick a different kernel at GRUB.

Comment: Hit the reset button.  You don't have anything to lose...